# How to count values from Python with loop

Tags: python, list

I want to count the number of TRUE in a table.  I wrote this code but it always returns `0`. What should I do?

```
def count(numbers):
    total = 0
    for x in numbers:
        if x == "True":
            total += 1
            
    return total

count(data['diabetes'])
```

Comment: You count the number of strings that are exactly `"True"` ...

Comment: Can you clarify your question? What does the input of `data['diabetes']` look like? What does it mean to be "True" (is it the string, which is what you are testing now, or is it the value `True`?

Answer (score 0):

If its a pandas `DataFrame`, you could `count()` the number of rows where the column of your choice fits your condition by:

```
data[(data['diabetes'] == True)].count()
```

Or just measure the `length`:

```
len(data[(data['diabetes'] == True)])
```

Answer (score 0):

Your table must have the truth value True instead of the string "True". The truth values can directly be checked in an if statement as:

```
if x is True:
    print("Yes")
```

or simply,

```
if x:
    print("Yes")
```

So now the code becomes:

```
def count(numbers):
    total = 0
    for x in numbers:
        if x:
            total += 1
            
    return total

count(data['diabetes'])
```